# gtest_output in MPI-Process

Tags: mpi, googletest

I'm working on an application that uses gTest with MPI. 
In gtest you can specify an output directory.
Either with an environment variable
`GTEST_OUTPUT` or a call parameter `-gtest_output`

My problem is that the parallel processes open the output file concurent. 
Is there a easy way to customize the path after launching the application?

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
int rank = 0;
MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, & rank);

std::string lfile = "json:"+out_"+itoa(rank)+".json";
testing::setOutputFile(lfile);
```

Comment: couldn't you adjust the `GTEST_OUTPUT` environment variable so that it is different for all processes? For example, you could include the rank of the MPI process somewhere into it. Most MPI implementation will set the rank as environment variable that you can use in the shell launching the binary. OpenMPI for example uses `OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK`, which you can use inside a shell that you launch with mpiexec, and which itself sets `GTEST_OUTPUT` using this rank variable, before to launch the actual binary...

Comment: Setting the `GTEST_OUTPUT` environment in the executable did not work for me: `setenv("GTEST_OUTPUT",file.c_str(),1);` the reason is that the variables are statically initalized. Maybe a wrapper script would work.
I found a Solution that ist not realy clean but works:
`namespace testing {
namespace internal {
namespace {
void setOutputFile(const std::string& txt) {
   GTEST_FLAG(output) = txt;
}}}}
`